# What is the meaning of the Error in loadNamespace

Tags: r, namespaces, rlang

```
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.2 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.5 is required
```

what does this mean

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please show us what your tried in your code, so will help you out.

Comment: It means you are trying to load a package (directly or implicitly) that requires a higher version of `rlang`; we don't know what you did to trigger this error, so it could be anything.  You might want to update your installation with `install.packages("rlang")`. If it complains about "package in use", or something, then restart R and reattempt installing rlang before trying to do what you did that triggered this error.